# Targetting the last element that has a tabindex attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

How do I target the last element of a given parent, that has a tabindex attribute?

For instance:

```
<div id="popup">
  <div id="some-element" tabindex="0">
  <div id="some-other-element" tabindex="0">
  <div id="yet-another-element" tabindex="0">
</div>
```

In this case it would target `#yet-another-element`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the attribute selector `[...]` combined with jQuery `.last()` :

```js
let target = $('#popup [tabindex]').last();
console.log(target.attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup">
  <div id="some-element" tabindex="0">
  <div id="some-other-element" tabindex="0">
  <div id="yet-another-element" tabindex="0">
</div>
```

---

Another way is to use jQuery `:last` selector :

```
$('#popup [tabindex]:last');
```

```js
let target = $('#popup [tabindex]:last');
console.log(target.attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup">
  <div id="some-element" tabindex="0">
  <div id="some-other-element" tabindex="0">
  <div id="yet-another-element" tabindex="0">
</div>
```

---

If you need to select a specific `tabindex` value :

```
$('#popup [tabindex="0"]:last');
```

Comment: Yeah, I know I am just saying for future use. This answer can satisfies multiple scenario.

Answer (score 1):

**Using JavaScript:**

Use [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with [`Attribute selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to get all the elements first in the form of an array-like object. Then use [`Spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`) and `array.length - 1` to take the element from the last index:

```js
var div = document.querySelectorAll('#popup > div[tabindex="0"]');
var lastEl = [...div][div.length - 1];
console.log(lastEl.id)
```

```html
<div id="popup">
  <div id="some-element" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div id="some-other-element" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div id="yet-another-element" tabindex="0"></div>
</div>
```

**Using jQuery:** You can use `:last` as part of the selector:

```js
var lastEl = $('#popup > div[tabindex="0"]:last');
console.log($(lastEl).prop('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup">
  <div id="some-element" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div id="some-other-element" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div id="yet-another-element" tabindex="0"></div>
</div>
```